# data.table manipulation and merging

Tags: r, data.table

I have data

```
dat1 <- data.table(id=1:8, 
                   group=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),                
                   value=c(5,6,10,11,12,20,21,22))
dat2 <- data.table(group=c(1,2,3), 
                   value=c(3,6,13))
```

and I would like to subtract `dat2$value` from each of the `dat1$value`, based on `group`.

Is this possible using `data.table` or does it require additional packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`, you could do:

```
library(data.table)

dat1[dat2, on = "group"][, new.value := value - i.value, by = "group"][]
```

Which returns:

```
   id group value i.value new.value
1:  1     1     5       3         2
2:  2     1     6       3         3
3:  3     2    10       6         4
4:  4     2    11       6         5
5:  5     2    12       6         6
6:  6     3    20      13         7
7:  7     3    21      13         8
8:  8     3    22      13         9
```

Alternatively, you can do this in one step as akrun mentions:

```
dat1[dat2, newvalue := value - i.value, on = .(group)]

   id group value newvalue
1:  1     1     5        2
2:  2     1     6        3
3:  3     2    10        4
4:  4     2    11        5
5:  5     2    12        6
6:  6     3    20        7
7:  7     3    21        8
8:  8     3    22        9
```

Comment: You could do this in one step `dat1[dat2, newvalue := value - i.value, on = .(group)]` and check `dat1`

Comment: Thanks akrun. I couldn’t figure out how to do it in one step. I’ll update my answer later, otherwise I’ll delete it if you answer with your solution

Comment: No, it's okay.  It is just a variation of your idea.  Please keep it

Comment: It'd be great if you could edit your answer to include akrun's and to update the resulting matrix. I could then delete my own answer and keep yours!

Comment: Didn't you want to include akrun's suggestion that does all at once? Also, your repost of the data is incorrect.

Comment: I did include his suggestion. And my repost of the data is incorrect because you edited your question and changed the data... @bumblebee

Comment: Exactly, this is why I asked to update it as my edits were rejected (by you or others).

Comment: Ah, I see now. I didn’t realize you changed the data until ~30 minutes ago. I will update when I’m done with work.

Comment: @bumblebee updated the solutions with the updated data